# Is there any possible way to implement Exoplayer in your app to play a Youtube live stream without breaking their TOCs?

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, youtube-dl

I've come across posts where they use an URL extractor (m3u8) and then use HLS to play Youtube live videos on Exoplayer. But I doubt the app might get taken down, If that method would be followed Not sure thou. It's a risk.

So, Are there any straight forward ways to play a Youtube live video using Exoplayer currently ?